# How to Create a Custom List or Library for each and every users in site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

How to Create a Custom List or Library for each and every individual users in site collection? or else shall i create a common library for whole site collection and then displays files only that created by particular user who currently signed in? or else what i can i do for this situation? In that site collection every user should maintain their own files that must be hide from others... like my folder...

Comment: If you accept that answer, you should probably delete this question. Or post it as an answer. Having it just in the body of your question is not really helpful

Comment: i thought i may helps to others, if some one comes like me, is there any problem for this post available here?

Comment: i can't post it in answer because i am new in this site so i can post only after 8 hours... so after 8 hours you can see this answers in my answer section. is it ok for you>?

Comment: Totally ok :) just wanted to make sure you would!

Answer (score 0):

Got anser from Stack overflow

If you want to let users manage their own files, using "My Site" features is probably the best, because it has been built for this purpose. However, because each personal site is a dedicated site collection, you may have to do some plumbing if you want to display this content from another application.